# when i search the item it shows parse error

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

When I search the item it shows parse error and giving the warning.how to remove this warning.
When I search the item it shows parse error and giving the warning.how to remove this warning.

How to get rid of this warning & error ?

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]: http://svcs.sandbox.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced&amp;SERVICE-VERSION=1.8.0&amp;GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US&amp;SECURITY-APPNAME=arifliaq-093e-43f2-a6ac-1e8ce8da2625&amp;keywords=110114826574&amp;paginationInput.entriesPerPage=1&amp;outputSelector=SellerInfo:1: 

parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 1 and head in C:\wamp\www\PHP_PlaceOfferGS_TradingShopping\Browsing.php on line 39"
```

**Code:**

```
<?php
require_once('./sessionHeader.php');
require_once('./SingleItem.php');
require_once('./keys.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);          // useful to see all notices in development
?>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Browsing on eBay</TITLE>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/JQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ShowDetails.js"></script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<H1>Browsing on eBay</H1>
<br>

<?php
global $shoppingURL,$appID,$eBayVersion,$findingURL,$compatabilityLevel, $findingVer;    // these come from keys.php
//need to urlencode the user-input keyword for the Finding API
$safeQuery = urlencode($_POST['QueryString']);
//construct the URL; we want to get only one returned item to keep things simple so   set entriesPerPage to 1
// (by default, only one page is returned)
$apicall  = "$findingURL?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced&SERVICE-VERSION=$findingVer"
        . "&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US"
        . "&SECURITY-APPNAME=$appID"
        . "&keywords=$safeQuery"
        . "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=1"
        . "&outputSelector=SellerInfo";


if ($debug) {
 print"<p>$apicall</p>"; //see what call is if we're debugging-$debug comes from keys.php
 }

 // Load the call and capture the document returned by the Finding API
 $resp = simplexml_load_file($apicall);

// Check to see if the response was loaded, else print an error
if ($resp) {
$results = '';
if ($resp->paginationOutput->totalEntries == 0) {
    $results .= "<BR>Sorry, there were no results found\n";
} else {
 $results .= "<DIV ALIGN=CENTER> \n";
 // If the response was loaded, parse it and build links
 // To keep things simple, we're showing only the first returned item;
 foreach($resp->searchResult->item as $item) {
 $browseItem = new SingleItem($resp->searchResult->item->itemId);
 $results .= $browseItem->getBrowseItemAsHTML_Table();
 $results .= "<form name=\"BidOrBuyIt\" method=\"post\" action=\"./Login.php\" >\n";
 $results .= "<INPUT TYPE=\"submit\" NAME=\"BidOrBuyIt\" VALUE=\"Bid or Buy It!\"> </form>\n";
 $_SESSION['ItemID'] = (string)$browseItem->resp->Item->ItemID;  // cast to string to keep in $_SESSION
 } // for each
 $results .= "</DIV> \n";
}
} else {
$results = "<BR>Sorry, did not receive a search result\n";
} // if $resp
print $results;
?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
![warning][1]
```

Comment: I try this but still error.how to remove this error?

Comment: $resp = simplexml_load_file($apicall);

Comment: the error of the above line

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in YOUR code, but in the XML that you are fetching from that ebay url. There is nothing you can do about it, other then contact ebay (somehow) and ask them to create well formed XML.

The most simple (but also the most bad) way to hide it, is using the @ suppression method.

```
$resp = @simplexml_load_file($apicall);
```

Comment: i try this,warning lose and no item search

Comment: this is not the best solution give another suggestion

Comment: This is the solution to the question you asked ("How to get rid of this warning & error ?"). It hides the error. You have a number of other logic issues in your code that need to be fixed before I could even try to give you further help on why it doesnt do what you want.

Comment: another method to pass url to the simplexml_load_file

Comment: plz help to remove this error

Comment: You got 0 search results because you were searching for "110114826574". I edited your url to search for a different keyword, and got results.

Comment: I try all these but no result

Comment: how to remove this error

Answer (score -1):

Edit `<br>` to `<br />` in your file. It comes often when you do not close the tags.

Comment: i try this but still error in the above file

Comment: $resp = simplexml_load_file($apicall);

Comment: the error on above line how to remove this error

Comment: this is not the best solution

Comment: plz help to remove this error